# How to make all pages of flutter app responsive?

Tags: flutter, responsive-design

How will I make all my pages responsive in a flutter app? Should I implement the responsive layout code in every pages or will it inherit the responsive layout from its parent(main.dart)? There are many tutorials on how to make an admin screen responsive.. But if a flutter app contains multiple pages, should I write different layout code for mobile, tab and desktop layout?

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/responsive/adaptive-responsive

Comment: There's nonsuch term as 'page' in Flutter. My advice is spend some time learning the fundamentals of Flutter

Comment: It depends on how you define a responsive screen for all pages... Some pages layout change drastically while others don't. You need to figure that out first. If you want, you can Wrap all your "pages" with a single `LayoutBuilder` and pass the dimensions as parameter so they rebuild every time viewport changes. A key also might help.

Comment: @MaximSaplin what I meant by page is different dart files which interact with users. Like login page, employee page, product page etc.

Comment: @ClevinoAlrin if I have product page and category page in my app, I have to design separately for each screen size with the help of refactoring widgets (to reduce code duplication)? Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, if your widgets have a similar structure and just difference in values or dimensions , you can refactor into a separate widget and use that widget by supplying parameters for values.

Comment: @user19976096 1 file is not necesseraly 1 page because you can create file for just widget that are part of pages. You should divide your pages as multiple reusable component and then create multiple layout depending on how you want your "pages" to behave depending on the support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good day!

In Our Mobile app, we use a combination of MediaQuery.of(context).size and widgets like SizedBox() to achieve responsiveness.
Example:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
     
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
            child: COntainer(),
            );
      }
    }
```

There is also the LayoutBuilder(), which you can use to build widgets with size parameters that you provide to the LayoutBuilder.
This might help: https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/responsive/adaptive-responsive